# How to make the apple into green text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a snake game from [Snake Code - Make the face of the snake an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234722/snake-code-make-the-face-of-the-snake-an-image), and I'm wondering how to make the apple into text with the same font as the Score in the upper right corner, and green using the JavaScript recognized color `LimeGreen`, or its Hex equivalent `#32CD32`.

Here's the continuous HTML code for your viewing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color: #000000">
<head>
  <title>Snake!</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    (function() {
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      // Canvas & Context
      var canvas;
      var ctx;
      
      // Snake
      var snake;
      var snake_dir;
      var snake_next_dir;
      var snake_speed;

      // Food
      var food = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };

      // Score
      var score;

      // Wall
      var wall;

      // HTML Elements
      var screen_snake;
      var screen_menu;
      var screen_setting;
      var screen_gameover;
      var button_newgame_menu;
      var button_newgame_setting;
      var button_newgame_gameover;
      var button_setting_menu;
      var button_setting_gameover;
      var ele_score;
      var speed_setting;
      var wall_setting;

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var activeDot = function(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "LimeGreen";
        ctx.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
      }


      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var changeDir = function(key) {

        if (key == 38 && snake_dir != 2) {
          snake_next_dir = 0;
        } else {

          if (key == 39 && snake_dir != 3) {
            snake_next_dir = 1;
          } else {

            if (key == 40 && snake_dir != 0) {
              snake_next_dir = 2;
            } else {

              if (key == 37 && snake_dir != 1) {
                snake_next_dir = 3;
              }
            }
          }
        }

      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var addFood = function() {
        food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((canvas.width / 10) - 1));
        food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((canvas.height / 10) - 1));
        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
          if (checkBlock(food.x, food.y, snake[i].x, snake[i].y)) {
            addFood();
          }
        }
      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var checkBlock = function(x, y, _x, _y) {
        return (x == _x && y == _y) ? true : false;
      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var altScore = function(score_val) {
        ele_score.innerHTML = String(score_val);
      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var mainLoop = function() {

        var _x = snake[0].x;
        var _y = snake[0].y;
        snake_dir = snake_next_dir;

        // 0 - Up, 1 - Right, 2 - Down, 3 - Left
        switch (snake_dir) {
          case 0:
            _y--;
            break;
          case 1:
            _x++;
            break;
          case 2:
            _y++;
            break;
          case 3:
            _x--;
            break;
        }

        snake.pop();
        snake.unshift({
          x: _x,
          y: _y
        });


        // --------------------

        // Wall

        if (wall == 1) {
          // On
          if (snake[0].x < 0 || snake[0].x == canvas.width / 10 || snake[0].y < 0 || snake[0].y == canvas.height / 10) {
            showScreen(3);
            return;
          }
        } else {
          // Off
          for (var j = 0, x = snake.length; j < x; j++) {
            if (snake[j].x < 0) {
              snake[j].x = snake[j].x + (canvas.width / 10);
            }
            if (snake[j].x == canvas.width / 10) {
              snake[j].x = snake[j].x - (canvas.width / 10);
            }
            if (snake[j].y < 0) {
              snake[j].y = snake[j].y + (canvas.height / 10);
            }
            if (snake[j].y == canvas.height / 10) {
              snake[j].y = snake[j].y - (canvas.height / 10);
            }
          }
        }

        // --------------------

        // Autophagy death
        for (var i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {
          if (snake[0].x == snake[i].x && snake[0].y == snake[i].y) {
            showScreen(3);
            return;
          }
        }

        // --------------------

        // Eat Food
        if (checkBlock(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, food.x, food.y)) {
          snake[snake.length] = {
            x: snake[0].x,
            y: snake[0].y
          };
          score += 1;
          altScore(score);
          addFood();
          activeDot(food.x, food.y);
        }

        // --------------------

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // --------------------

        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
          activeDot(snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
        }

        // --------------------

        activeDot(food.x, food.y);

        // Debug
        //document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = snake_dir + " " + snake_next_dir + " " + snake[0].x + " " + snake[0].y;    

        setTimeout(mainLoop, snake_speed);
      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      var newGame = function() {

        showScreen(0);
        screen_snake.focus();

        snake = [];
        for (var i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
          snake.push({
            x: i,
            y: 15
          });
        }

        snake_next_dir = 1;

        score = 0;
        altScore(score);

        addFood();

        canvas.onkeydown = function(evt) {
          evt = evt || window.event;
          changeDir(evt.keyCode);
        }
        mainLoop();

      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      // Change the snake speed...
      // 150 = slow
      // 100 = normal
      // 50 = fast
      var setSnakeSpeed = function(speed_value) {
        snake_speed = speed_value;
      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      var setWall = function(wall_value) {
        wall = wall_value;
        if (wall == 0) {
          screen_snake.style.borderColor = "#606060";
        }
        if (wall == 1) {
          screen_snake.style.borderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        }
      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      // 0 for the game
      // 1 for the main menu
      // 2 for the settings screen
      // 3 for the game over screen
      var showScreen = function(screen_opt) {
        switch (screen_opt) {

          case 0:
            screen_snake.style.display = "block";
            screen_menu.style.display = "none";
            screen_setting.style.display = "none";
            screen_gameover.style.display = "none";
            break;

          case 1:
            screen_snake.style.display = "none";
            screen_menu.style.display = "block";
            screen_setting.style.display = "none";
            screen_gameover.style.display = "none";
            break;

          case 2:
            screen_snake.style.display = "none";
            screen_menu.style.display = "none";
            screen_setting.style.display = "block";
            screen_gameover.style.display = "none";
            break;

          case 3:
            screen_snake.style.display = "none";
            screen_menu.style.display = "none";
            screen_setting.style.display = "none";
            screen_gameover.style.display = "block";
            break;
        }
      }

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      window.onload = function() {

        canvas = document.getElementById("snake");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Screens
        screen_snake = document.getElementById("snake");
        screen_menu = document.getElementById("menu");
        screen_gameover = document.getElementById("gameover");
        screen_setting = document.getElementById("setting");

        // Buttons
        button_newgame_menu = document.getElementById("newgame_menu");
        button_newgame_setting = document.getElementById("newgame_setting");
        button_newgame_gameover = document.getElementById("newgame_gameover");
        button_setting_menu = document.getElementById("setting_menu");
        button_setting_gameover = document.getElementById("setting_gameover");

        // etc
        ele_score = document.getElementById("score_value");
        speed_setting = document.getElementsByName("speed");
        wall_setting = document.getElementsByName("wall");

        // --------------------

        button_newgame_menu.onclick = function() {
          newGame();
        };
        button_newgame_gameover.onclick = function() {
          newGame();
        };
        button_newgame_setting.onclick = function() {
          newGame();
        };
        button_setting_menu.onclick = function() {
          showScreen(2);
        };
        button_setting_gameover.onclick = function() {
          showScreen(2)
        };

        setSnakeSpeed(150);
        setWall(1);

        showScreen("menu");

        // --------------------
        // Settings

        // speed
        for (var i = 0; i < speed_setting.length; i++) {
          speed_setting[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < speed_setting.length; i++) {
              if (speed_setting[i].checked) {
                setSnakeSpeed(speed_setting[i].value);
              }
            }
          });
        }

        // wall
        for (var i = 0; i < wall_setting.length; i++) {
          wall_setting[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < wall_setting.length; i++) {
              if (wall_setting[i].checked) {
                setWall(wall_setting[i].value);
              }
            }
          });
        }

        document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
          if (screen_gameover.style.display == "block") {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
              newGame();
            }
          }
        }
      }

    })();
</script>
<style>
    ::selection {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background: transparent;
    }

     ::-moz-selection {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background: transparent;
    }

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "VT323";
    }

    body {
      background-color: #000000;
    }

    .wrap {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    header {
      width: 340px;
      font-size: 0;
    }

    canvas {
      display: none;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 10px;
      border-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    canvas:focus {
      outline: none;
    }


    /* Top Styles */

    h1 {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .score {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 240px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .score_value {
      font-size: inherit;
    }


    /* All screens style */

    #gameover a,
    #setting a,
    #menu a {
      display: block;
    }

    #gameover a,
    #setting a:hover,
    #menu a:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #gameover a:hover::before,
    #setting a:hover::before,
    #menu a:hover::before {
      content: ">";
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


    /* Menu Screen Style */

    #menu {
      display: block;
      width: 340px;
      padding-top: 95px;
      padding-bottom: 95px;
      font-size: 40px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    #menu h2 {
      -webkit-animation: logo-ani 1000ms linear infinite;
      animation: logo-ani 1000ms linear infinite;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    #menu a {
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes logo-ani {
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
      }
    }

    @keyframes logo-ani {
      50% {
        transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
      }
    }


    /* Game Over Screen Style */

    #gameover {
      display: none;
      width: 340px;
      padding-top: 95px;
      padding-bottom: 95px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    #gameover p {
      margin-top: 25px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }


    /* Settings Screen Style */

    #setting {
      display: none;
      width: 340px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      padding-top: 85px;
      padding-bottom: 85px;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #FFF;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #setting h2 {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #setting p {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    #setting input {
      display: none;
    }

    #setting label {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #setting input:checked+label {
      background-color: #FFF;
      color: #000;
    }
</style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <header class="wrap">
      <h1>Snake</h1>
      <p class="score">Score: <span id="score_value">0</span></p>
    </header>

    <canvas class="wrap" id="snake" width="600" height="600" tabindex="1"></canvas>

    <!-- Game Over Screen -->
    <div id="gameover">
      <h2>Game Over</h2>
      <p>press <span style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000">space</span> to begin a</p>
      <a id="newgame_gameover">new game</a>
      <a id="setting_gameover">settings</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Setting screen -->
    <div id="setting">
      <h2>Settings</h2>

      <a id="newgame_setting">new game</a>

      <p>Speed:
        <input id="speed1" type="radio" name="speed" value="120" checked/>
        <label for="speed1">Slow</label>
        <input id="speed2" type="radio" name="speed" value="75" />
        <label for="speed2">Normal</label>
        <input id="speed3" type="radio" name="speed" value="35" />
        <label for="speed3">Fast</label>
      </p>

      <p>Wall:
        <input id="wallon" type="radio" name="wall" value="1" checked/>
        <label for="wallon">On</label>
        <input id="walloff" type="radio" name="wall" value="0" />
        <label for="walloff">Off</label>
      </p>

    </div>

    <!-- Main Menu Screen -->
    <div id="menu">
      <h2>Snake</h2>

      <a id="newgame_menu">new game</a>
      <a id="setting_menu">settings</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 3rd param to activeDot, pass the colour.

```
var activeDot = function(x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
}
```

It's used in 3 places, `activeDot(food.x, food.y, 'LimeGreen');`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Lawrence_Cherone!

Comment: Wait, I put the 3rd parameter, as well as a 4th parameter that lets me draw text, but it doesn't work. The JSFiddle snippet is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0yhubaes/). Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: is unclear what your trying to do but here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/13850m67/

Comment: I'm trying to advance that snake game, so instead of having the snake eat an apple, the snake eats the one or two letters displayed, which is actually the abbreviation of an element in the Periodic Table. When the snake eats the element abbreviation, an alert box opens, and tells about the element. Don't do research to get the information about the elements, just leave that part to me. Get the code structure, and place a JavaScript `\\comment` where I type in the information. Don't go too far and make it into a continuous HTML code, just keep editing the page you saved on JSFiddle.

Comment: Wait, about your comment, I'm new here, and I just accepted your answer, but I can't upvote your answer, since I only have 11 reputation. I will upvote your question, though, when I get 15 reputation.